# do not refresh page upon form submit

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to submit this form without refreshing the page. I'm using jquery; upon submit the page still refreshes.

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#container').append('loading');
      var sthis = $('#sthis').val();
      $.ajax({
         url: 'f.php' , 
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'sthis: ' + sthis,
         success: function(result){     
           $('#container').append('<p>' +     result + '</p>')      
         }
      });   
      return false;     
   });
});
```

html page (f.php)

```
<div id="container">
<form method="post" action="f.php">
something<input name="sthis" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="#submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

php page

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sthis'])){
  $sthis = $_POST['sthis'];
  if(empty($sthis)) { echo 'put something in this box'; }
  else echo 'ready';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is here  
id="#submit" should be id="submit", that should work.

Comment: won't this reload the f.php page after ajax response is received, due to action="f.php"?

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="#submit" />
```

To this:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="#submit" />
```

Then hook up an event handler that calls your ajax function, instead of submitting the form.

Comment: Problem there is if the user hits "enter" in the input box, they will still trigger the form submit event.

Comment: agreed, if the form submits, the page will refresh, which could be caused, among other things, but an enter in a text field

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do in this case is change your form tag like so:

```
<form method="post" action="f.php" onSubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: when i do this the form does nothing, even if the field is empty

Comment: Something else must be going on, then.  It shouldn't have any affect on your jquery ajax code.  Are you getting a JS error?

Answer (score 1):

in your form tag, just add an `onsubmit="return false"`. That will prevent the form from submitting it's request and refreshing your page.  The click event on that button will still work so you can control everything via javascript.  Here's more info:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html

Comment: when i do this the form does nothing, even if the field is empty

Answer (score 0):

There is still something wrong.

First: in f.php:

```
 <input name="sthis" type="text" />
```

Change it to :

```
 <input id="sthis" type="text" />
```

Second: the data format in .ajax is wrong:

```
  data: 'sthis: ' + sthis,
```

Change it to:

```
 data: {sthis: sthis},
```